# Mongoskin findAndModify ID object id

Tags: mongoskin

Using nodejs, mongoskin..  I'd like to return the updated doc so Im using findAndModify, however the query {_id: "someid"}  doesn't work.   I think I need to use {id: ObjectID{'someid'} as the query.  How do I get the ObjectId type into JS?

Answer (score 13):

try this:

```
ObjectID = require('mongoskin').ObjectID

{_id: new ObjectID("someid")}
```

Comment: this one did it for me

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution

```
var mongo = require("mongoskin");
var conn = mongo.db(YOUR_DETAILS);
var BSON = mongo.BSONPure;
```

this enables you to convert your id int, string or whatever using:

```
conn.collection(YOUR_COLLECTION).find({_id:new BSON.ObjectID(YOUR_ID)})
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
yourCollection = db.collections('yourCollection');
```

Then

```
{ _id: yourCollection.id("someId") }
```